# I Cant see all the values in my Code? it only Display the First Word

Tags: php, html

[In the "description" i want to display all 3 to 4 words but only displays the first word... help please](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25unV.png)

Comment: Post your code here and the generated output.

Answer (score 0):

use PHP strpos or substr

```
$pos=strpos($record['description'], ' ', 4);
echo substr($record['description'],0,$pos );
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of why only the first word is currently being displayed..